# Get a selection of Data from JSON using Javascript (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How to get a selection from JSON data (from PHP URL) and move it into a different variable and make a filtered version the data. I want to push data into a variable selected by "kabupaten" and "bulan" on JSON keys

JSON data sample:

```
 [  
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberASMAT",
      "kabupaten":"ASMAT",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"16725"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberBOVEN DIGOEL",
      "kabupaten":"BOVEN DIGOEL",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"29985"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberMAPPI",
      "kabupaten":"MAPPI",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"19193"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberMERAUKE",
      "kabupaten":"MERAUKE",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"150717"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberMIMIKA",
      "kabupaten":"MIMIKA",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"213536"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberNDUGA",
      "kabupaten":"NDUGA",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"2879"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberPEGUNUNGAN BINTANG",
      "kabupaten":"PEGUNUNGAN BINTANG",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"8474"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberPUNCAK",
      "kabupaten":"PUNCAK",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"5652"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10DesemberYAHUKIMO",
      "kabupaten":"YAHUKIMO",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"15315"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberASMAT",
      "kabupaten":"ASMAT",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"18731"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberBOVEN DIGOEL",
      "kabupaten":"BOVEN DIGOEL",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"29716"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberMAPPI",
      "kabupaten":"MAPPI",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"18801"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberMERAUKE",
      "kabupaten":"MERAUKE",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"151950"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberMIMIKA",
      "kabupaten":"MIMIKA",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"213225"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberNDUGA",
      "kabupaten":"NDUGA",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"3808"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberPEGUNUNGAN BINTANG",
      "kabupaten":"PEGUNUNGAN BINTANG",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"7438"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberPUNCAK",
      "kabupaten":"PUNCAK",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"5846"
   },
   {  
      "x":"10NovemberYAHUKIMO",
      "kabupaten":"YAHUKIMO",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"17420"
   },
```

I want to select only kabupaten: ASMAT and push it into a new variable
Like This:

```
 {  
      "x":"10DesemberASMAT",
      "kabupaten":"ASMAT",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"16725"
   },
{  
      "x":"10NovemberASMAT",
      "kabupaten":"ASMAT",
      "tanggal":"10",
      "bulan":"November",
      "device_count":"18731"
   },
{  
      "x":"11DesemberASMAT",
      "kabupaten":"ASMAT",
      "tanggal":"11",
      "bulan":"Desember",
      "device_count":"16891"
   },
```

Here is my Push code in AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/coba/data.php",
    type : "GET",
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
      console.log(data);

      var tanggal = [];
      var count_november = [];
      var count_desember = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        tanggal.push(data[i].tanggal);
        count_november.push(data[i].device_count);
      }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`<script>
    var datas = [
        {
            "x":"10DesemberASMAT",
            "kabupaten":"ASMAT",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"16725"
        },
        {
            "x":"10DesemberBOVEN DIGOEL",
            "kabupaten":"BOVEN DIGOEL",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"29985"
        },
        {
            "x":"10DesemberMAPPI",
            "kabupaten":"MAPPI",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"19193"
        },
        {
            "x":"10DesemberMERAUKE",
            "kabupaten":"MERAUKE",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"150717"
        },
        {
            "x":"10DesemberMIMIKA",
            "kabupaten":"MIMIKA",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"213536"
        },
        {
            "x":"10DesemberNDUGA",
            "kabupaten":"NDUGA",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"2879"
        },
        {
            "x":"10DesemberPEGUNUNGAN BINTANG",
            "kabupaten":"PEGUNUNGAN BINTANG",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"8474"
        },
        {
            "x":"10DesemberPUNCAK",
            "kabupaten":"PUNCAK",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"5652"
        },
        {
            "x":"10DesemberYAHUKIMO",
            "kabupaten":"YAHUKIMO",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"Desember",
            "device_count":"15315"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberASMAT",
            "kabupaten":"ASMAT",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"18731"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberBOVEN DIGOEL",
            "kabupaten":"BOVEN DIGOEL",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"29716"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberMAPPI",
            "kabupaten":"MAPPI",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"18801"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberMERAUKE",
            "kabupaten":"MERAUKE",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"151950"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberMIMIKA",
            "kabupaten":"MIMIKA",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"213225"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberNDUGA",
            "kabupaten":"NDUGA",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"3808"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberPEGUNUNGAN BINTANG",
            "kabupaten":"PEGUNUNGAN BINTANG",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"7438"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberPUNCAK",
            "kabupaten":"PUNCAK",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"5846"
        },
        {
            "x":"10NovemberYAHUKIMO",
            "kabupaten":"YAHUKIMO",
            "tanggal":"10",
            "bulan":"November",
            "device_count":"17420"
        }
    ]
    var new_datas = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < datas.length;i++) {
        if(datas[i]['kabupaten'] == 'ASMAT') {
            new_datas.push(datas[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(new_datas);
</script>`

Comment: Yes actually solved by your code (if statement). I got inspiration from that thank you

Comment: How i make kabupaten value become dynamic (value depend on option on html)

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain? Thanks for accept this answer.

Comment: if(data[i].kabupaten == (value from JQUERY) && data[i].bulan == (value from JQUERY))
        {
        tanggal.push(data[i].tanggal);
        count_november.push(data[i].device_count);
        }
        if(data[i].kabupaten == (value from JQUERY) && data[i].bulan == (value from JQUERY))
        {
        count_desember.push(data[i].device_count);
        }

Like This

Comment: You can (value from JQUERY) define in the ajax success. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an example of something you are trying to do. If you have more questions or it is not quite what you are looking for let me know and I will continue to work on it with you.

```
const kabupatenFiltered = DATA.filter(element => {

   const arrayKeyValues = Object.entries(element)

   return arrayKeyValues[1][1] === 'ASMAT' 

 })
```

Comment: This solution is dynamic, which is what I think you were aiming for. The 'ASMAT' can also be whatever you need it to be. Also can change the key to whatever you need it to be.